# Enable sudo -f option in 12.04 LTS

Tags: sudo

How is it possible to enable the

> sudo -f
>   option in 12.04 LTS?

Comment: This is an option for su rather than sudo as far as I know... If you like I can write this up as a formal answer.

Comment: I Dont think this is the case: ~$ su --help
Usage: su [options] [LOGIN]

Options:
  -c, --command COMMAND         pass COMMAND to the invoked shell
  -h, --help                    display this help message and exit
  -, -l, --login                make the shell a login shell
  -m, -p,
  --preserve-environment        do not reset environment variables, and
                                keep the same shell
  -s, --shell SHELL             use SHELL instead of the default in passwd

Comment: The -f in su is something else (--fast) and is not a --force.

Comment: Looks like the recompile option will be the correct answer but look here for the su -f option: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html. I have cast a red herring I am afraid in your question :(

Answer (score 2):

sudo has no -f option.  If it had the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/sudo.8.html) would have it listed and it would also not need "enabling".

```
sudo -f
sudo: invalid option -- 'f'
usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user]
usage: sudo -l [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-U user] [-u user]
            [command]
usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p
            prompt] [-u user] [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [<command>]
usage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p
            prompt] [-u user] file ...
```

---

Regarding comment and the [link](http://chneukirchen.org/blog/archive/2011/04/sudo-f.html%22):

> I quickly checked the sources, and it turns out that this feature needs to be enabled during compliation with the `--enable-force` flag.
>
> As far as I can tell, Arch and Debian don’t have this feature enabled, and neither does Gentoo, which not even provides a use-flag for it. It is, however, turned on by default on Ubuntu (after all, they make heavy use of sudo), RHEL, Fedora Core (since version 12), and openSUSE

I can not find any reference to the claim Ubuntu supports this. Nor any other system using "sudo". If Debian does not support it I seriously doubt Ubuntu does. Our system tends to stick to Debian and if we ever deviate from Debian in the long run we always tend to stray back to how Debian does it.

Oh and the man page your link claims has "-f" listed does not list "-f". It it existed in 2011 it does no longer.

The link also claims you can get it working by recompiling "sudo". But still I would assume that the "sudo" website would list it as a compile option and I have not seen it.

Comment: Yes, I know all this. Yet the people at OpenSTM32 use it for installing the OpenSTM32 Workbench:

Comment: Sorry my previous comment got posted prematurely. If you look at http://www.openstm32.org/Installing+System+Workbench+for+STM32+with+installer?structure=Documentation you will see the command "sudo install_sw4stm32_linux_64bits_vX.X.run -f". Also, under "http://chneukirchen.org/blog/archive/2011/04/sudo-f.html" there explicit reference to it enabled "by default" under Ubuntu. Yet again, on the SUDO web page (http://www.sudo.ws/) I couldn't find it.

Comment: That 1st link requires a login. The 2nd one talks about recompiling sudo with an option set

Comment: Yes, this is the conclusion I was coming ot as well. I just have to decide whether I want to give myself this donkey work... Thanks anyway.

Comment: I opened the source for 1.8.12 and the `--enable-force` option is not there as a ./configure option:  http://pastebin.com/6Tb2A0qz . Attempting to run it, in case it is an undocumented option, gives an 'Unrecognized option' warning.